# DataTables not parsing data-filter attribute

Tags: jquery, heroku, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net) jquery plugin (on my rails app)

My table is set up with rows like:

```
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><a class="songAnchor">Random Song Name</a></td>

  <!-- This is the bit that matters!!! -->
  <td data-filter='nasty_song overrated'>
    <span>Nasty Song</span>
    <span>Overrated</span>
  </td>

</tr>
```

I have a custom filter that uses toggleable buttons on this page. Here is the code for my filter:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    if (active_filter_count == 0)
        return true

    var keys = data[2].split(" ")
    for (i in keys)
    {
        if (active_filters[keys[i]] == 1)
            return true
    }
    return false
  }
);
```

But `data[2]` isn't what I expected. I was expecting:

```
"nasty_song overrated"
```

What I'm getting is:

```
"Nasty Song                             Overrated"
```

So DataTables isn't grabbing the data from the `data-filter` attribute (it's just stripping html from the cell). What's weird is that the above code works as expected in my local environment but not when I push to Heroku. There are no errors in the console. How do I even go about figuring out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain but it seems that the problem was that I left `data-filter=''` blank in the `td`s that didn't have any tags.

I think that setting `data-filter='0'` has solved the problem.